# Calendar from scratch, how to select day only in one month?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am looking for help. I am trying to add extra feature to calendar. If user select 1 or more days, this day/s will be selected. Problem is if I select one day in month, calendar select this specific day in all months. For example, If I select day second in June, calendar select day second in all months.
How can I fix it? Thank you.

here is link for project: https://calenda-next-js.vercel.app/

```
const handleClick = (e) => {

   let m = e.currentTarget.children[0].children[1].textContent.split('|')[0] 
   console.log('selected month: ' + m) 

   let d = e.target.textContent 
   console.log('selected day: ' + d)  

   let c = e.target
   console.log('selected span: ' + c)  
   
    if(m && d) {
      c.classList.add("selected") // add orange background
   }  
 }
```

I added handleClick to div and find specific element by children selection. Not sure, if this is best way but it is working. Best way would be to add handleClick to span, I thought if I found current month and specific day it select only specific day..

```
<div className="datePicker" onClick={handleClick}> // <<<<<<< handleClick

         <div className="pickerHeader">
            <button onClick={ handlePrevClicked }>
                Prev 
            </button>
            <h1>
              {MONTHS[currentMonth]} 
              <small>
                &nbsp; | &nbsp; {currentYear}
              </small>
            </h1>
            <button onClick={ handleNextClicked }> 
             Next 
            </button>
         </div>

         <div className="weekHeader">
            <span>Su</span>
            <span>Mo</span>
            <span>Tu</span>
            <span>We</span>
            <span>Th</span>
            <span>Fr</span>
            <span>Sa</span>
         </div>

         <div className="dates">

            { Array.from({ length: currentStartingDay },
               (i) => ( 
               <span className="empty" key={i} /> )) 
            }

            { 
             Array.from({ length: currentLastDay }, (_, d, i) => (
               <span className={ isToday( d + 1 ) ? "active" : "" } 
                     key={i} >
                { d + 1 }
               </span>  )) 
            }

         </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things here.

First of all, you are using a `key` that is just an index of a day

```
<span className={ isToday( d + 1 ) ? "active" : "" } key={i} >
```

It means that for any month, for the same days, these indexes will be the same, hence, once selected for one month makes a day (visually) selected for all months. However, this shouldn't matter once you fix the way how you keep the selection state (see below).

Second, to make a day selected, you cannot rely on the added class name to the component in the `React` app as you do here

```
c.classList.add("selected")
```

`React` can re-render the component, and the state will be lost. Instead, you need to use the se `useState()` hook to keep the selection state and update it in `handleClick()`. Then, your render code must check if the day is selected in the state and render accordingly.